# Finding 2nd highest <attribute>

Tags: sql

I have a table bills(name char(30),amount int, account_id int). I am trying to find out the 2nd highest amount from the table. Sample data is as below:

```
Name              | Amount  | Account_ID
Phoness Company   | 125     | 1
O Company         | 127     | 2
Phoness Company   | 187     | 1
sdfkjlef          | 45      | 3
```

My code below returns 125. It should return 127. Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
select min(amount) from (select top 2 amount from bills) b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost done:

```
select min(amount) from (select top 2 amount from bills order by amount desc) b
```

In case, if in your table there is more than one rows with highest value you can use this:

```
select min(amount) from (select distinct top 2 amount from bills order by amount desc) b
```

Comment: I thought so, Thanks I got it.